# Store jQuery objects in an array/object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a JS array that contains jQuery objects like this:

```
var oFormFields = new Object;
oFormFields.label = $(document.createElement('label'));
oFormFields.input = $(document.createElement('input'));
```

Since this crashes my code, i expect this is not possible. Any alternatives? This is my simplified version, I want to include some other properties so I'm able to re-use this in my code when building dynamic forms.

EDIT: Seemed this did work after all... what I wanted to do, was something like this:

```
var oFormFields = new Object;
oFormFields.name_field.label = $(document.createElement('label')).addClass('nam_field');
oFormFields.name_field.input = $(document.createElement('input')).addClass('nam_field');
```

This does break my code. I'm pretty new to jQuery, coming from a PHP background I'm having some troubles adjusting to the correct way to work with arrays / objects.

Comment: This code is working perfectly fine. It doesn't crash. But please, don't use "new Object" - use the literal version {}.

Comment: @JohannesLumpe Why shouldn't he use new Object out of curiosity?

Comment: Well it isn't doing any harm if that's what you're asking about. It's just that {} is more concise and in fact "new Object" and "{}" do exactly the same thing - the constructor is called behind the scenes if you use the literal version. In this case it's more about a clear coding style than about harm ;)

Comment: @bo-oz: your updated example breaks, because you are trying to set "label" and "input" on "name_field", which doesn't exist. If you had used the object literal like it's used in the accepted answer, you would have instantly noticed the error :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use it like this:

```
var oFormFields = {
  label: $('<label />'),
  input: $('<input />')
};
```

You can [create the element directly using jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2). Furthermore, as mentioned in the comments, you should prefer the object literal notation over the `new` syntax.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes, no reason why not. Object properties can be functions, and functions can return things. You'd obviously need to initialise `oFormFields` first, though.

Comment: Thanks.. I think the problem was I was using a different notation. I wanted to store all the labels and fields in one array. I'll update the code to reflect this..

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [];
var oFormFields = {};
oFormFields.label = $('<label/>');
oFormFields.input = $('<input/>');

arr.push(oFormFields);
.........
```